# XPATH: Finding the following-sibling from the parent of an xpath

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to determine the correct xpath for this HTML layout. I can only be sure of the name of the first element (input id="urn..."). I need to get to the parent of input (div), and then to the following sibling (ul), and then to the first child (li).

My xpath looks like this:

```
    "//input[contains(@id, "city~HOME_CITY")]/parent::div/following-sibling::ul/li[1]"
```

I'd be much obliged if someone could look over this. It seems like finding the (/parent) or (/following-sibling) has been consistently difficult for me to make work in any context. I'm new to this, so if anyone would like to critique other aspects of my approach I'd be very grateful!

[HTML tree pictured here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzXBR.jpg)

Comment: It looks OK to me (except that the string "city~HOME_CITY" is enclosed in double-quotes (rather than single quotes), within a double-quoted string. I assume the outer quotes are delimiting a Python string that contains the XPath expression? Apart from that, though. It looks OK. Is not working? What kind of result do you get?

Comment: The quotes are ok, it's correct in my code. My script is just simply not finding that element. I have these two lines in my code:

        dropX = '//input[starts-with(@id, "urn:li:fs_easyApplyFormElement")][contains(@id, "city")]/parent::div/following-sibling::ul[1]/li[1]'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(dropX).click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright haha, welp as I said, beginner mistake XD. Given the picture I sent, I didn't realize I'm looking for the parent of the parent (2 divs up). Whoops. Simple fix by adding another /parent::div and bam all fixed up. Thanks to everyone for the suggestions, will definitely streamline it later!

Comment: For future reference, this is why it's better to include your actual markup in a code block, rather than a screenshot; if people have the actual data they can test it, rather than rely on eyeballing it..

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine! A very slightly shorter equivalent would be:

```xml
//div[input[contains(@id, 'city~HOME_CITY')]]/following-sibling::ul/li[1]
```

Essentially replacing the `parent::` step from the `input` to the `div` with a predicate on the `div` that tests if it has an `input` child.

You might want to put a `[1]` predicate after the `ul` step, too, if there might be more `ul` siblings.

Comment: It looks like my script isn't finding that element for some reason. I've had similar problems when trying to find elements based on parent. For some context, this is a drop-down menu that only appears after an input is made. However I've done this before, minus the same xpath, and it's executed perfectly. It is finding the initial element, just not the parent/following-sibling part. Here is my code:

        dropX = '//input[contains(@id, "city~HOME_CITY")]/parent::div/following-sibling::ul[1]/li[1]'
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(dropX).click()

Answer (score 0):

{div id="ember505"} is the parent for child 1  (div-> grand child [input]) and child 2 (ul-> li[1])
currently you are traversing from grand child [input] to child (div) it should not be the case get to the parent {div id="ember505"} then traverse to the second child (ul->li[1])